# SimpleStocks protocol usage (Apple sample code)

Tags: objective-c, syntax, protocols

In the [SimpleStocks](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/SimpleStocks/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code provided by Apple, dataSource is defined as follows:

```
property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <APLSimpleStockViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

and then used variously as follows (only 2 examples, but there are more in the code)

```
NSInteger dataCount = [self.dataSource graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self]; 
NSArray *sortedMonths = [self.dataSource graphViewSortedMonths:self];
```

I understand what graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount does, and also graphViewSortedMonths.I would have understood: `NSInteger dataCount = [APLStockViewController graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self];` (Tried that, and I think I know why that can't work)

Here's the rub: The way I read the 1st line of code, dataSource is being sent the message graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount (which returns some numeric value specifying how many transactions occurred). If we assume 25 transactions, essentially [dataSource 25]; 
And now my mind is boggling, because I am strongly expecting that somewhere, there would be code telling dataSource what to do with the 25 it is being sent. But there isn't!!!

Then the boggling increases by an order of magnitude: dataSource having been sent the 25, it now returns that and puts it into dataCount. How does it know to do that, there's no code anywhere that I can find for that either.

And now, tickle me ballistic, in the second line of code, dataSource knows to accept (and then return) an NSArray.

In my ever rarer sane moments, it looks to me like dataSource really doesn't do anything other than "pass through" stuff that it gets handed. Computers can't do magic, it feels like a feature, but where is it documented ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's the rub: The way I read the 1st line of code, dataSource is being sent the message graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount (which returns some numeric value specifying how many transactions occurred).

Correct.

> If we assume 25 transactions, essentially [dataSource 25];

Incorrect (based on the [] and your description, you think we're sending 25 to the data source).
After the call, `dataCount = 25`.

The call is asking the data source to return data to us. It is passing ourself to the data source (`:self`) for information purposes but the intent of the request is to get information from the data source.

Now that we have the 25 (stored in `dataCount`) we can do something with it.

Similarly, in the second line of code, the data source is just returning the array. We aren't passing it an array.

For the previous mini question:

> NSInteger dataCount = [APLStockViewController graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self];

This can't work because `APLStockViewController` is a class. We need to talk to an instance of the class (which is where `self.dataSource` comes in).

Comment: Thanks, but am I not in fact doing this:
'NSInteger dataCount = [[self dataSource] graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self];'
and isn't that:
first getting a pointer to the dataSource object using an (implicit) getter (with the '[self dataSource]' snippet, 
second, sending that object the message graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount: (with a parameter self), which, 
third, causes the object to return (an NSInteger) which is stored in dataCount? But how does the dataSource object know how to return that NSInteger (and later an NSArray) if it doesn't have any methods?   
Sorry for being so obtuse.

Comment: (Thanks to Josh Caswell for pointing out the non-dot syntax equivalent. Aaron Hillegass' Obj-C BNR Guide does suggest to avoid dot notation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over complicating how delegates and datasources work. Datasource points to some instance of some object.

When some object said it was a `APLSimpleStockViewDataSource`, it was saying that it implemented some methods, including `graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:` and `graphViewSortedMonths:`. That object has `SomeInstanceOfAPLSimpleStockView.datasource = self` (or whatever the name of the class that you're working in was) somewhere in it's creation, like `init` or `viewdidload`

It's the same as if you had some 
`MyObject* myobj` that implemented those methods, and you called `[myobj graphViewSortedMonths:self`

Comment: I just reread the last paragraph of your post...That part is correct. A datasource is simply a pointer with some handy features

Comment: "It's the same as if you had some MyObject* myobj that implemented those methods, and you called [myobj graphViewSortedMonths:self"
That's it! Thanks Anthony (and Stack Overflow)